# Python and Qt - function reloading

Tags: python, function, reloading

i have an application class inherited from QtGui.QDialog.
I have to reload show-function but save functionality. I take this idea from C#.
There i could do something like this:

```
static void show()
{
  // My code...
  base.show();
}
```

I want to do something like that but with python and qt (PyQt). Can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [super()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#super) function but note some [pitfalls](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275).

Comment: Btw for Qt you can just do QClass.show(self) and it will call the base class.